Why iOS duplicates SIP call screen?
I use linphone app to receive SIP calls on my iPhone with iOS 17. When SIP call is received, I get it in linphone app and in standard iPhone's app. And sending of DTMF signals work thru standard app only.
What is the reason to display the call twice? Is there any way to avoid it?

What do you mean with "display twice"? Does it show in both when the call comes in (rings)? Or does it just show up in the call history in both apps?

It shows in both when the call comes.

Here is the video to demonstrate the problem: https://youtube.com/shorts/FQ2JiOG5CYc?feature=share
